Is my marriage still valid if my husband doesnt pay mehr before due date?
Salam alaykum,
Is my marriage contract still valid if my husband doesnt pay the mehr?
1st he told me to make it affordable for him so i lowered my mehr to $1000. When the imam asked me when the mehr would be paid my husband answered before i could. And it is due in roughly less than a month.
If he has not paid the mehr by said date is our marriage contract still valid?
I cant find an answer anywhere. And nothing i find seems to relate to my situation.

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and the SE model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Wa'lekumassalam warahmatullah ukhti and yes marriage is valid. Still, for not paying the Mahr your husband will be taken accountable if he didn't pay however consult to him wisely about this. You can also take it on part by part basis, but anyway your marriage is valid and if he doesn't pay you the mahr he did a great sin and he leaved his fard that Allah ordained and he will surely be taken accountable for that. Rest Allah knows best
